# Are photos in 'Photo' on MacBook the same resolution as original photos on iCloud?

Tags: photos, storage, resolution

I store all my photos on iCloud.  I want to make a backup of all my photos (60 000-odd) on a removable storage unit.  This is easy if I select all photos in 'Photo' on my MacBook and drag these to my portable storage unit.  My question is, will the resolution of these dragged photos be the same as the originals stored on the iCloud?

Comment: I won't put this as an answer as I don't know the exact syntax and would never use Photos in any case.  You want to tick the "Download Originals" option, otherwise you are not guaranteed that the images on your computer are not just thumbnails.

Comment: @MarcWilson - thanks.  Your uncertainty is exactly the point of my question.  Downloading from iCloud has a limit of 1000 images at a time and is also VERY slow.  I'm wanting to know if I get the same resolution if I export from 'Photos' on my MacBook to my external device (as I would get downloading the same photos from iCloud).

Comment: You didn't read what I said.  Nowhere did I mention downloading from iCloud.  What I said was to configure Photos.app to download the original images, which is a capability it has.  Again, unless you've configured Photos.app to "Keep Originals" or "Download Originals", or whatever it calls it, you have zero assurance that what you're copying out of the library aren't just the thumbnails.

Comment: Whether you'd get the actual images, or edits you'd applied to them in Photos.app, is also a consideration.  Some people would think backups would be the originals, some the edits, some would want both.

Comment: @MarcWilson - thanks again!  I've checked my preferences for 'Photo' on my MacBook and the versions on my computer ARE '...full resolution originals...'.